# XHTML Column Padding Bug

Tags: xhtml, html-table, padding

Try setting the padding of `<td>` to more than 1px, you can't.

You can only specify 0 or 1px padding for this td. But why ? It's same in both transitional and strict document types.

http://www.pro-turk.net/xhtml_col.html

Comment: For me, changing the padding on the td works just fine. What browser?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably that you are not defining the unit for the padding. setting it something like `10px` (in chrome at least) works fine.

Comment: And I thought I was being slow :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're specifying the padding as `1` - no units - rather than `1px`, `1em`, etc.

It's fine to specify `0` without units, as `0` is the same in any unit - but not 1.